# My iPhone 5s will not sync with my iTunes anymore!

Tags: iphone, itunes

My iPhone 5s will not sync anymore. iTunes reads it once it's plugged in and comes back with an error message saying "You do not have enough access privileges for this operation.".

Comment: Check this ;  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4023481

Answer (score 1):

I have only seen this with beta versions of the OS and/or iOS.

The first step is going to be to reproduce the problem.

1. Connect everything power off the iPhone
2. Save your work on the Mac and shut it down as well
3. Power on the iPhone and then put it in airplane mode
4. Start the Mac and fire up iTunes (only iTunes if possible )

Then keep good notes on what you see - all dialogs and exact text, what operation causes the issue and the times. From there, you can look over access logs and iTunes logs on the Mac and/or get support involved to read the legs from the iOS device if needed.

Feel free to comment or ask a follow on question once you have it pinned down. For me, the restarts fixed the issue or it was a server side issue and not reproducible past the time Apple's servers were busy or slow.

Comment: The 1. Instruction came out a little weird, can you clarify?